How to create Machine Learning model in Snowflake that accepts input data via API?
Using my snowflake trial account, I have successfully created ML model and store them in the Snowflake model registry.
However, I could not figure out how to create REST API endpoint that accepts input parameters and somehow programmatically pass the data to Snowflake model for prediction purpose.
For example, Is it possible to create a FASTAPI server or serverless script that can remotely invoke snowflake user defined function (which then invokes the ML model)?
Or is there any better approach?
optimised_params = {'n_estimators': 5, 'min_samples_split': 5, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_depth': 5, 'bootstrap': False}

rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier(**optimised_params)
rf_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


from snowflake.ml.registry import Registry

reg = Registry(session=session)

reg.log_model(
model_name="employee_attrition",
model=rf_clf,
sample_input_data=X_train)
reg.show_models()``

Would be great if some expert can point me to the sample working project / code for this use case.
